# phonegap file .bithoundrc and ignored files

Tags: phonegap-build, phonegap, phonegap-cli

I've noticed a file in phonegap called .bithoundrc

I searched for it's use but didn't get good info

I know that it ignores some file

I have also a js file and i want to ignore it in build

will this file ignore it?

thank you all .